# Как синтезировать речь из текста на Английском и Русском языке?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, синтезатор-речи

Как синтезировать (генерировать) речь (озвучить текст) на Английском и Русском языке (текст в речь)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого вам поможет класс `TextToSpeech`. Доступен с версии `Android 1.6+`.

**Пример:**

```
TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
textToSpeech.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

ссылка на документацию - [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)